# How to remove a Neutrik 4 way loudspeaker coupler

Tags: connector

I'm sure there's a knack to it, and hopefully I'm not being too dumb, but does anyone have any tips on how to remove this device from one of our cables?

https://www.digitec.ch/en/s1/product/neutrik-4-way-loudspeaker-coupler30a-250vac-cables-plugs-9941657

It's a Neutrik cable interconnector, allowing a user to combine two cables in to one large one.

We've managed to remove the cable one side of the device without problem, but not the other.  We've passed it round multiple people, and even tried to use screwdrivers etc to force the object, however non of our group is able to take it off. I just don't see how it works.

I would prefer not to have to replace the connector on the end of the cable just to remove this device, or alternatively, use a sledge hammer :)

Thanks,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a specific vendor hardware question and nothing at all to do with sound design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slide the collar to unlock the coupler.

Slide the latch on the plug away from the coupler, then twist anti-clockwise to release.

https://www.neutrik.com/media/8072/download/speakon-nl4mmx-coupler.pdf?v=1

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I guess I wasn't turning the cable as per step C) part b in the pdf.